# WcfFacility and Sequence contains no elements error?

Tags: castle-windsor, castle, wcffacility

I have wcf library with service contracts and implementations.

```
     [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceProtoType 
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Response GetMessage(Request request);

        [OperationContract]
        String SayHello();

    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Request
    {
        private string name;

        [DataMember]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Response
    {
        private string message;

        [DataMember]
        public string Message
        {
            get { return message; }
            set { message = value; }
        }

    }
 public class MyDemoService : IServiceProtoType
    {
        public Response GetMessage(Request request)
        {
            var response = new Response();
            if (null == request)
            {
                response.Message = "Error!";
            }
            else
            {
                response.Message = "Hello, " + request.Name;
            }
            return response;
        }
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello, World!";
        }
    }
```

I have windows service project that references this library, where MyService is just an empty shell that inherits ServiceBase. This service is installed and running under local system.

```
static void Main()
        {
          ServiceBase.Run(CreateContainer().Resolve());
        }

        private static IWindsorContainer CreateContainer()
        {
            IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
            return container;
        }

 public class  ServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {

        #region IWindsorInstaller Members

        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
        {

            string myDir;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath))
            {
                myDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            }
            else
            {
                myDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
            }

            var wcfLibPath  = Path.Combine(myDir , "WcfDemo.dll");
            string baseUrl = "http://localhost:8731/DemoService/{0}";
            AssemblyName myAssembly = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(wcfLibPath);

            container
                .Register(
                    AllTypes
                        .FromAssemblyNamed(myAssembly.Name)
                        .InSameNamespaceAs<WcfDemo.MyDemoService>()
                        .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
                        .Configure(c =>
                                   c.Named(c.Implementation.Name)
                                       .AsWcfService(
                                           new DefaultServiceModel()
                                               .AddEndpoints(WcfEndpoint
                                                                 .BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding())
                                                                 .At(string.Format(baseUrl,
                                                                     c.Implementation.Name)
                                                                 )))), Component.For<ServiceBase>().ImplementedBy<MyService>());
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

In Client Console app I have the following code and I am getting the following error:
{"Sequence contains no elements"}

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
            string baseUrl = "http://localhost:8731/DemoService/{0}";
            container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>(f => f.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero);

            container
                .Register(
                    Types
                        .FromAssemblyContaining<IServiceProtoType>()
                        .InSameNamespaceAs<IServiceProtoType>()
                        .Configure(
                            c => c.Named(c.Implementation.Name)
                                     .AsWcfClient(new DefaultClientModel
                                     {
                                         Endpoint = WcfEndpoint
                                             .BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding())
                                             .At(string.Format(baseUrl,
                                                 c.Name.Substring(1)))
                                     })));


            var service1 = container.Resolve<IServiceProtoType>();

            Console.WriteLine(service1.SayHello());

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: I don't know what else to try, from what I can tell the client is not finding any implementations. I am not sure if it is a wcf configuration problem or if it just can't find the service contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea what this may be but you can stop reading this now (and I apologize for wasting your time in advance) if the answer to the following is no:

**Is one (or more) of `Request`, `Response`, or `MyDemoService` in the same namespace as `IServiceProtoType`?**

I suspect that Windsor is getting confused about those, since you are doing...

```
Types
    .FromAssemblyContaining<IServiceProtoType>()
    .InSameNamespaceAs<IServiceProtoType>()
```

... and then configuring everything which that returns as a WCF client proxy.  This means that it will be trying to create proxies for things that should not be and hence a `Sequence Contains no Elements` exception (not the most useful message IMHO but crushing on).

The simple fix would be just to put your `IServiceProtoType` into its own namespace (I often have a namespace like `XXXX.Services` for my service contracts).

If that is not acceptable to you then you need to work out another way to identify just the service contracts - take a look at the `If` method for example or just a good ol' `Component.For` perhaps.

Comment: I think you are correct since they are all in the same namespace, I will follow your suggestion and move the service contract into it's own namespace, and let you know how it goes, I do think from what I saw in debug it was trying to create proxies for things that should not be.